# approximation in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I read the following result in real analysis:

> Let $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $k \geq 0$. Then the space $C^\infty_c({\bf R}^d)$ of test functions is a dense subspace of $W^{k,p}({\bf R}^d).$

A known proof is given, for instance, in a lecture [note](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/) (Lemma 2).
I was told that this is not generally true for arbitrary open set $\Omega$ of ${\bf R}^d$. But I can't see why the proof of the statement above would break down if one just replaces ${\bf R}^d$ with $\Omega$. Would anybody point out where could possibly go wrong?

---

The following is the proof for the above statement:
[image]

Comment: The problem in this proof is that it uses convolution which is not defined on arbitrary domains, only on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you try to redo this proof on a domain, first of all you will have to deal with the boundary which is going to get in your way. You can eventually get out of this (see any textbook on Sobolev spaces) but the only functions that you will be able to approximate with compactly supported functions are going to be those that vanish at the boundary.

Comment: Nice introductory textbooks on those things are Brezis's or Evans's books on PDEs or Folland's "Real Analysis". But there are a lot of references

Answer (score 1):

(This was supposed to be a comment but it is a bit too long)

If you take the $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,p}}$ closure of compactly supported functions you only get the functions that vanish at the boundary. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is no boundary, so no problem. Similarly with higher order Sobolev spaces: on $W^{k,p}$ the closure of $C^\infty_c$ consists of those functions that vanish at the boundary with their $k-1$ derivatives.